# Converting C function to assembly

Tags: assembly, sparc

Hi i am trying to convert this C function that I wrote to assembly code(SPARC arc)but keep getting a segmentation fault(core dumped) error. The function is supposed to convert a string to a long value. I know I did the C function correctly as I have tested it and it passed all the tests. Here is the C function I am trying to convert.

```
long strToLong(char *str, int base )
{
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  long num;
  num = strtol(str, &endptr, base);
  char holder[BUFSIZ];

  /*if *endptr isn't '\0' then strtol didn't get to the end of the string
  *so it wasn't a valid integer*/
  if(*endptr != '\0')
  {
    (void)fprintf(stderr, "\n\t""'%s'" "  is not an integer\n", str);
     return 0;
  }
  /*if errno isn't 0 then an error occured so print out an error message*/
  else if(errno != 0)
  { 
    (void)snprintf(holder, BUFSIZ,"\n\tConverting \"%s\" base \"%d\"\n caused an         ", str, base);
    perror(holder);
    return 0;
  }

  /*if no errors, then it was a valid integer so return the integer*/
  return num;
}
```

Here is the assembly code I wrote.

```
.global strToULong

.section ".data"    

fmt1:    .asciz    "%s  is not an integer\n"    !ascii format

fmt2:
    .asciz    "Converting %s base %d\n"    !ascii format

.section ".text"

strToULong:
    save    %sp, -( 92 + 1028) & -8, %sp
    add    %fp, -4, %o1
    mov    %i0, %o0
    mov    %i2, %o2
    call    strtol
    nop
    mov    %o0, %l0
    ld    [%fp - 4], %l1
    ldub    [%l1], %l1
    cmp    %l1, %g0
    be    errno
    nop

    set    stdError, %o0
    ld    [%o0], %o0
    set    fmt1, %o1
    mov    %i0, %o2
    call    fprintf, 3
    nop

errno:
    mov    %l0, %i0
    set    errno, %l2
    ld    [%l2], %l2
    cmp    %l2, %g0
    be    return
    nop

    add    %fp, -1028, %o0
    mov    1024, %o1
    set    fmt2, %o2
    mov    %i0, %o3
    mov    %i1, %o4
    call    snprintf
    nop
    add    %fp, -1028, %o0
    call    perror
    nop
    mov    0, %i0

return:
    ret
    restore
```

I debugged the program and the seg fault comes when I call the strtol function. Im not really sure what im doing wrong, I think I am passing the parameters correctly but I still get that error. Oh and in my main i have something declared like FILE* StdError = stderr to pass stderr as a parameter to fprintf.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Did you try dumping the code generated by the C compiler?

Comment: nvm, i actually don't really understand what you mean by that.

Comment: objdump -d yourcbinary should give you the assembly produced by compiler

Comment: Nowadays the canonical way of converting C to assembly is by using a compiler :-) Try `gcc -S`

Comment: haha but i'd assume i'd get in trouble by my professor if i did it that way. Maybe I can do that and try to compare to see what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple different problems going on around there, but one that you can fix pretty easily would be the way you're accessing errno. You shouldn't have a branch named errno, because you also have a global var errno, and that can cause some confusion.

Since errno is a global variable, loading errno into a register should look like this:

```
    set errno, %l0    !sets %o0 to a pointer to errno
    st %g0,[%l0]      !set errno to 0

    set %i0, %o0      !move str to output
    set endptr, %01   !move endptr to output (defined above in .section ".data")
    set %i1, %o2      !move base to output

    call strtol,2     !calls strtol with given inputs
    nop

    ld  [%l0], %l1    !loads the value at errno into %l1
```

In this example, %l0 holds a pointer to errno, and %l1 holds the value at errno after calling strtol. Then you can error check with:

```
    cmp %l1,%g0       !compares errno to 0
    be endif
    nop

    /* if body */

endif:

    /* continued code */
```

That should get you past a few of your problems. As you're writing assembly, it really helps to comment it up like crazy, both with ! after each line, and a block at the top where you keep track of local vars. Assembly isn't nearly as straightforward to look at, so it really helps.